# See stacktrace after deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

My application is being executed in debug mode and then deadlock happens. Is there any way to see the stacktrace before deadlock or at least the last called method?

Comment: Can't you just 'Break', then look at the different threads call stacks...

Answer (score 19):

Click BreakAll (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>) and open Debug->Windows->Threads

There you can see stacktrace for every thread

Comment: Thank you! So easy... I am embarassed :)